# Выполнить безопасный запрос с помощью PDO

Tags: php, mysql

// Как выполнить данный запрос максимально безопасно и просто с помощью PDO

```
$var="";
$var1=0;

if(isset($_GET['priceFrom'])){
$var = " `pris` > ". $_GET['priceFrom'];
$var1=1;
}
if(isset($_GET['priceUpTo'])){
if($var1==1){
$var1 = $var1 . " AND `pris` < " .  $_GET['priceUpTo'];
}else{
$var = " `pris` > ". $_GET['priceUpTo'];
}
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM object WHERE $var ");
```

Comment: Функции `mysql_*` УСТАРЕЛИ!!! В php 7 их уже нет. Если вы ими пользуетесь, да еще ТАК!!! как у вас в вопросе, то с вашей базой любой школьник может сделать все что угодно.

Comment: НУ я сам ещё школьник ) А что вы предлагаете?

Comment: Подготовленные выражения и PDO http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#prepared ВАЖНО: Подготовленные выражения - основная причина использовать PDO, поскольку это единственный безопасный способ выполнения SQL запросов, в которых участвуют переменные.

Comment: Спасибо, полезно сейчас изменю вопрос.

Comment: С учетом того, что сказал Visman, строите свой запрос кусками, примерно так как вы это и написали. добавляя в переменную части запроса, только в виде `поле=?` и кладя при этом в массив аргументов требуемые значения. И да, в итоге просто подставляете в запрос собранный кусок условий. Только между условиями пробелы бы не помешали

Comment: Спасибо,Mike, буду пробовать!

Answer (score 0):

PDO::prepare — Подготавливает запрос к выполнению и возвращает ассоциированный с этим запросом объект

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

// подключился с базе данных с помощью $pdo

```
$var='';
$var1=0;
if(isset($_GET['priceFrom'])){
$var = " pris > ". $_GET['priceFrom'];
$var1=1;
}
if(isset($_GET['priceUpTo'])){
if($var1==1){
$var1 = $var1 . " AND pris < " .  $_GET['priceUpTo'];
}else{
$var = " pris > ". $_GET['priceUpTo'];
}
}

$priceFrom = ($_GET['priceFrom']);
$priceUpTo = ($_GET['priceUpTo']);
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM object WHERE " . $var);
$sql->execute(array($priceFrom, $priceUpTo));

var_dump($sql->fetch());
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать PDO и забиндить параметры, например так

```
$st = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `object` WHERE pris > :pris');
$st->bindParam(':pris', $_GET['priceUpTo']);
$st->execute();
```

Если ожидается цифровой параметр то можно сделать до запроса `$_GET['priceUpTo'] = intval($_GET['priceUpTo']);`

Comment: А если каких то параметров не будет например $_GET['priceUpTo' , а будет только  $_GET['priceFrom']; будет работать?

Comment: Тогда биндите только те параметры что есть

Comment: Можете показать в вашем решении, я не понимаю